# spark-submit with python entry points

Tags: python, apache-spark, entry-point, spark-submit

I have a script `wordcount.py`
I used setuptools to create an entry point, named `wordcount`, so now I can call the command from anywhere in the system.
I am trying to execute it via spark-submit (command: `spark-submit wordcount`) but it is failing with the following error:

`Error: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/usr/local/bin/wordcount
Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output`

However the exact same command works fine when I provide the path to the python script (command: `spark-submit /home/ubuntu/wordcount.py`)

Content of wordcount.py

```
import sys
from operator import add

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def main(args=None):
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: wordcount <file>", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)

    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("PythonWordCount")\
        .getOrCreate()

    lines = spark.read.text(sys.argv[1]).rdd.map(lambda r: r[0])
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')) \
                  .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
                  .reduceByKey(add)
    output = counts.collect()
    for (word, count) in output:
        print("%s: %i" % (word, count))

    spark.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Do you know if there is a way to bypass this?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `spark-submit wordcount`, it treats wordcount as the jar file which will have the class to be executed.
Also, it tries to find the jar in the path `/usr/local/bin` as you have not specified the classpath.
Please provide the contents of the `wordcount` file. If possible try to give the path to `wordcount` while executing with `spark-submit`.

Check this link for more Info. on the spark-submit command: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you rename your entry point to have a `.py` suffix, `spark-submit` will accept it as a python application:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'wordcount.py = mymodule.wordcount:main',
    ],
}
```

Then the submission is accepted as expected:

```
spark-submit ./bin/wordcount.py
```